# Lookup Checkbox selected values from sharepoint list to Gallery

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

I have a gallery checkbox with selected values "A","B","C" and stored with a unique number "RAN-123", If I have to retrieve the record RAN-123 it does not showup the selected checkbox, I tied writing lookup function but unable to figure out. I tried below code

If(!IsBlank(item),LookUp(Records,Number=item).'Adders')

Item is Ran-123
Records is sharepoint list
Adders is column name (Choices) in sharepoint list